# How can I define a variable in a SQL query saved in a jinja2 template and have it substituted with a value when the query is run by ansible?

Tags: postgresql, ansible, jinja2, ansible-template

In my Ansible playbook, there is a task which runs a SQL query saved in a Jinja2 template on my database.

```yaml
- hosts: "{{ hosts_list }}"
  gather_facts: no

  vars_files:
    - vars/main.yml
    - vars/my_hosts.yml
    - vars/target_date.yml

  tasks:
    - name: generate report
      community.postgresql.postgresql_copy:
        login_host: '{{ db_host }}'
        login_user: '{{ db_username }}'
        login_password: '{{ db_password }}'
        db: '{{ db_database }}'
        port: '{{ db_database_port }}'
        src: "{{ lookup('template', 'my_report_query.sql.j2') }}"
        copy_to: /tmp/my_report.csv
        options:
          format: csv
          delimiter: ';'
          header: yes
```

The query is something like:

```sql
select * from mytable where date='2023-02-03';
```

Now, I would like to pass to the query a value of the date which is defined in my Ansible playbook.

So, in the case there would be a variable defined in my Ansible playbook as

```yaml
input_date: "2023-05-03"
```

saved in file `playbooks/my_playbook/vars/target_date.yml`

How can I edit my playbook and Jinja2 template in order to pass that variable to the query?

Comment: `select * from mytable where date='{{ input_date }}';`. Since you are calling the file from a template lookup, it will be templated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Ansible, you don't pass variables to your templates -- a template has access to all variables that are currently in scope. In other words, you just need to make sure that you've sourced that `target_date.yml` file.  For example, here we're doing that with the `include_vars` module:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    db_host: localhost
    db_username: example_user
    db_password: example_pass
    db_database: example_db
  tasks:
  - name: read vars file
    include_vars:
      file: vars/target_date.yml

  - name: generate report
    community.postgresql.postgresql_copy:
      login_host: '{{ db_host }}'
      login_user: '{{ db_username }}'
      login_password: '{{ db_password }}'
      db: '{{ db_database }}'
      port: '{{ db_database_port|default(5432) }}'
      src: "{{ lookup('template', 'my_report_query.j2.sql') }}"
      copy_to: /tmp/my_report.csv
      options:
        format: csv
        delimiter: ';'
        header: yes
```

We could also read in the vars file:

- By using the `-e` option on the `ansible-playbook` command line:

  ```bash
  ansible-playbook playbook.yaml -e @vars/target_date.yaml
  ```
- By using the `vars_files` option in the play:

  ```yaml
  - hosts: localhost
    vars_files:
    - vars/target_date.yml
  ```
- By setting the `input_date` variable in an appropriate file in the `group_vars` or `host_vars` directories.

Etc.

---

Note that for your playbook to work, you'll need to drop the `;` in your query template. With the terminal semicolon your copy task will fail with:

```
Cannot execute SQL 'COPY (select * from mytable where date='2023-05-03';
) TO '/tmp/my_report.csv' (format csv, delimiter ';', header True)': syntax error at or near ";"
LINE 1: COPY (select * from mytable where date='2023-05-03';
                                                           ^
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @β.εηοιτ.βε , it was sufficient to replace the hardcoded value of the date in jinja2 templates with the jinja2 ["expression](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#expressions) [tags"](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/) `{{ ... }}`

```sql
select * from mytable where date='{{ input_date }}'
```

also, as indicated by @larsks, the query in the jinja2 template must not end with column ( `;` )